# Simple Parse Push Notification Android

Tags: android, push-notification

I am using simple push notifications in my Android app. I am getting notifications fine, but my concern is while my app is running and if notification arrives and user clicks on it, it launches another instance of my app. I want to avoid stacking of my app. I am using [Parse Sdk](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart_push#android/existing) for push notification  Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

This is my code

```
 Parse.initialize(this, "123456789..", "12345697...");
 PushService.subscribe(context,"", Demo.class);
 PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, Demo.class);
```

Comment: can you update your question with code you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Use `addFlags` and set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` ,`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` ,`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Ex:

```
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(LiveChat.this,
            0, myIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Where do I add these flags?